# Web service throwing exception and doesn't return a response

Tags: wcf, web-services, exception

I'm calling out a web service (https://gw.sam.gov/epls/services/EPLSSearchWebService?wsdl) from a console application.  I just need to run "doSsnSearch" with a SSN and Name and confirm if there is a successful return result.  in 29 out of my 30 test records, nothing is returned, but when there is a valid response, the service throws an exception and the response is never returned.  The exception is as follows:

```
Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'doSsnSearch'.
```

The inner exception is:

```
{"Cannot assign object of type System.String[] to an object of type System.String."}
```

I am using a service reference to add the WSDL and have tried increasing the size of everything in readerquotas and everything else I could think of on the configuration end.  The worst part of this is that I fixed it before, but now I forgot what I did :\

I have confirmed that the web service call works with the data I am providing through use of SoapUI and I'm able to get a valid response.

Here's the calling code:

```
var client = new EPLSSearchWebServiceClient();
var query = new OperationSsnSearch 
{
  exactName = "XXX",
  ssnOrTin = "xxxxxxxxx"
};

var response = Client.doSsnSearch(query);  <--- exception is thrown here
```

Here's my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="EPLSSearchWebServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="999999" maxBufferPoolSize="999999" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999" maxStringContentLength="999999" maxArrayLength="999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://gw.sam.gov/epls/services/EPLSSearchWebService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EPLSSearchWebServiceSoapBinding"
            contract="SAMWebServices.EPLSSearchWebService" name="EPLSSearchWebService"/>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
...
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

edit: This is the body of the service that I'm calling:

```
 public SAM_Caller.Console_App.SAMWebServices.EPLSSearchResponse doSsnSearch(SAM_Caller.Console_App.SAMWebServices.OperationSsnSearch query) {
        SAM_Caller.Console_App.SAMWebServices.doSsnSearchRequest inValue = new SAM_Caller.Console_App.SAMWebServices.doSsnSearchRequest();
        inValue.query = query;
        SAM_Caller.Console_App.SAMWebServices.doSsnSearchResponse retVal = ((SAM_Caller.Console_App.SAMWebServices.EPLSSearchWebService)(this)).doSsnSearch(inValue);
        return retVal.doSsnSearchReturn;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get more specific information as for where the error happens. Is it on the server or client side? (I assume client). Does the client sends a request and get a response (use fiddler to check) or does the error happen before sending something?

Next you want to make sure you have generated the proxy from the latest WSDL version. Possibly the server has changes since you generated the proxy so you should issue an update.

Finally, this may be a bug in WCF proxy generation. If you could not solve it with my previous suggestions, then please publish here the response soap and the code of the service proxy (reference.cs).

Comment: The error is on the server.  Nothing gets returned to the client.  I have the latest WSDL. I'll post the code of the service above

Comment: Wow, you were right.  It looks like they changes the address of the WSDL within the last few days.  Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is clearly stating your issue. You trying to assign an array of String to a String. Please check your code where you are doing this assignment.
Most probably the function call is returning an String array so firstly check for return type of that function. 
Check what you are assigning to response.

I don't exactly know in which language you are coding but telling you the simplest approach which you can refer. I will be more than happy if you resolve this issue b checking only this simplest thing.

Comment: This is C#.  All the code that I'm using to run this service is included here.  Client.doSsnSearch(query) is third party code and I can't step into it.  The exception is throw before the function returns, so 'response' never gets a value.

Comment: Ok. don't step into it but check for your own satisfaction if approach works.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is the code that is doing this is assignment is not available to view for me.  When there are no results, the exception is not thrown, but for a specific query with a name and ssn, when there are results to return, the exception is thrown.

Comment: Ok then you should specify the Variable response as and String Array . e.g String[] response = Client.doSsnSearch(query);  When there are no results Null value is getting assigned which is a valid value for any object. I THINK SO.

Comment: The WSDL provides a specific return type (EPLSSearchResponse), so I can only compile if my return value is that or "var"

Comment: Friend I am a Java guy and I think your problem may be syntax related one. You need to check with that. You can check with your EPLSSearchResponse if it helps you.